# Condition "if" using "&&" statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

i've got a problem when i want to control what i want to insert in my SQLite database.

I use "if" condition and statement "&&" like that :

```
 if (addDream.isPressed() && lucidbtn.isChecked()) {
        carnet.setText(editDream.getText().toString());
        carnet.setLucid(1);
        cn.insertNoteReve(carnet);
        editDream.setText("");
        xp = exp.xpUp(30);
        user.setExperience(xp);
        userDao.expUp(user);

    }
```

That works, my xp (here 30) is insert in my database correctly.
But when i want to add a second "&&" statement like that:

```
else if(addDream.isPressed() && lucidbtn.isChecked() && wild.isChecked()) {
        carnet.setText(editDream.getText().toString());
        carnet.setLucid(1);
        cn.insertNoteReve(carnet);
        editDream.setText("");
        xp = exp.xpUp(70);
        user.setExperience(xp);
        userDao.expUp(user);
    }
```

This doesn't work, that only insert 30 and no 70. I think the problem is with the second "&&" statement because i tried with another condition without "lucidbtn.isChecked" and the value was modified in the database.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: We don't know what's is checked or pressed in your UI... Hard to help without knowing that

Comment: isCheck are 2 ToggleButtons, and isPressed is a simple button who send all of the data entered by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting `else if`, only the first condition will be executed because it matched first.

If you want to either insert 30 or 70 from that specific wild check, then you can use a ternary and a single if statement

```
if(addDream.isPressed() && lucidbtn.isChecked()) {
    carnet.setText(editDream.getText().toString());
    carnet.setLucid(1);
    cn.insertNoteReve(carnet);
    editDream.setText("");
    xp = exp.xpUp(wild.isChecked() ? 70 : 30);
    user.setExperience(xp);
    userDao.expUp(user);
}
```

Or you need to check `if (wild.isChecked())` within this block separately, not as part of all conditions

Comment: Ok thanks, i completly restructure my conditions.
I use one "if" with `if(addDream.isPressed && lucidbtn.isChecked())` and i put `if(wild.isChecked)` inside and the others togglebuttons i need.
Thanks, I understand my mistake, sorry if my english was bad and the misplaced question :)